# To hide a google sheet based on another sheet's cell value in a google spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet for requirement gathering with multiple sheets in it.

I want to hide some sheets based on a condition in a spreadsheet.

Example:

There are 4 sheets in a spreadsheet-
`sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and sheet4`

by default all sheets should be hidden

`sheet1` has the values as conditions

[image]

Now, if only if sheet2 is marked `Yes`then the `sheet2` should unhide and sheets `sheet3` and `sheet4` should be hidden.

Similarly, only the `Yes` against each sheet name should unhide the respective sheets.

How can we do this in Google sheets with clicks or with a Google apps script.

I searched for a lot but only got answers for hiding cell ranges not sheets/tabs. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  var cellv = sheet3.getRange('B4');
 
  if (cellv.getValue() == 'No') {
    sheet1.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cellv.getValue() == 'Yes') {
    sheet1.showSheet();
  }

  var cellc = sheet3.getRange('B5');

  if (cellc.getValue() == 'No') {
    sheet2.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cellc.getValue() == 'Yes') {
    sheet2.showSheet();
  }

  var cellb = sheet3.getRange('B7');

  if (cellb.getValue() == 'No') {
    sheet4.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cellb.getValue() == 'Yes') {
    sheet4.showSheet();
  }
}
```

The function will run based on the values displayed on the cells, the code could be improved by retrieving the range values from `B4:B7` but if you will only use 4 sheets then this should do the work.

This is how it will work:

[image]

In my testing scenario I was using `sheet3` to retrieve the cell value but you can modify it as you need.

Comment: I'm glad that was what you wanted!